# OpenWhisk action opening file gets file not found exception, but file exists

Tags: java, io, openwhisk

Testing my action via wsk command when in the vagrant VM it gets the parameters successfully but when attempting to open a file it throws:

```
FileNotFoundException: /ild/data/workspaceArtifacts/workspaceArtifacts_bc3d43ab-1529-41c8-8571-b7155e53e3ff.json
```

However, when I list the file it is there:

```
ls -l /ild/data/workspaceArtifacts/workspaceArtifacts_bc3d43ab-1529-41c8-8571-b7155e53e3ff.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 37457375 Jul  6 21:57 /ild/data/workspaceArtifacts/workspaceArtifacts_bc3d43ab-1529-41c8-8571-b7155e53e3ff.json
```

Does OpenWhisk (running locally) have sandbox limitations for where it is allowed to open files? My action is a Java action and I'm attempting to open a FileReader.

All directories referenced are owned by vagrant:vagrant and have read permissions for all.

Answer (score 0):

Openwhisk runs actions inside a docker container and the files outside the container won't be visible to the action. You can zip the files along with the code and create the action. You can look at this for reference. 
https://www.raymondcamden.com/2017/01/10/creating-packaged-actions-in-openwhisk
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_actions.html#openwhisk_actions